# How do I pick a wife?

Tags: guild-2

In the Guild 2 I'm getting ready to court my first spouse, and from a guide I read it recommended picking a spouse whose class complimented mine (ie: Patron for Craftsman).  How do I determine the class of a potential spouse, they seem to all say 'Unemployed`?

Comment: Change this title to "How do I pick a wife?" and then we'll talk.

Comment: This title's pretty good too.  I can imagine some guy walking into a bar and thinking "I'm a tank, which woman in here looks like a healer?"

Comment: So 2 tipsy DPS walk into a bar... the third one ducks!

Comment: The healer then whinges about the DPS taking environment damage.

Comment: Another classic gaming title, I love it.

Answer (score 2):

The class of the character is displayed on courtship dialog screen, but this requires you to run to the location of the character before finding out.

Comment: no. You dont have to run anywhere. you can just open possible candidates for your character while having the character selected and click court. Click on each candidate in order and at the top, it displays their class. You can just stand in one place and find this out.